# Typesetting $e$

Tags: soft-question

Should the Euler constant (or exponential constant) $$e$$ be typeset in italics or non-italics (\text), per mathematical convention and also best practice for mathematical typography?

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Mathematics#Roman_versus_italic).

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, and is between you and your advisor, editor, or publisher.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it should be used in italics itself.
Because all the constants (of 1 letter) are italicized like,

> $c$ - speed of light
> $k$ - Boltzmann constant
> $R$ - gas constant

and so on.

$e$ although transcendental, is a constant. So it should be italicized. But when we write it as functions like $\sin$, $\log$, $\arg$, $\arccos$, it should be non-italicized-  $\color{blue}{\exp}$